# Setting LayoutParams twice, no effect?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, layoutparams

I'm doing this in Monodroid(C#) but I'm sure most of you understand anyway. I need to move a certain textview in intervalls. The first aligning to its parent left works fine. Then i wait 4 seconds and want it to align right of the parent, which gives no effect at all. It stays left. How come?

Example (C#)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView.LayoutParameters;
newParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft);
textView.LayoutParameters = newParams;


System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams2 =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView.LayoutParameters;
newParams2.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);
textView.LayoutParameters = newParams2;
```

Really odd since it works flawless the 1st time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after setting new layout parameters, you need to call `requestLayout()` on your view to take effects.

> **requestLayout()**
>
> Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout
>   of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.

so you should call:

```
textViewToAnimate.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Tried both this and ForceLayout() without effect :(

Comment: Why was this accepted if it did not work? Can you let us now how you got it working with this?